# jquery tools: Calling doc ready initialization in script loaded by ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, tabs, initialization

I have a jquery tools based tabs working great, and on each tab I load pages using ajax.  One of the pages has got tools from another party, which requires the following code be run when ready:

```
$(function() { $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane({showArrows: true}); });
```

I'm note sure where to put this code (in the ajax loaded page).  According to the flowplayer guys:

"The script tag should be placed below the HTML elements not inside the document.ready()  event because that event is not fired for the pages that are loaded with AJAX."

Does that mean encapsulate the above in `<script></script>` tags, and place after the `</html>` tag?  That's outside the whole doc so it doesn't seem right...

Help anyone...where should I put my initialization code in the ajax doc?

Thanks

Comment: It sounds like it should just be before `</body>`.

Answer (score 0):

Run it as a callback for the AJAX load, this way the code will be run after the HTML has been loaded into the DOM.

```
$('#result').load('ajax/test.html', function() {
  $(function() { $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane({showArrows: true}); });
});
```

Read more in the [API for `load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

Comment: This answer seems obvious and redundant there must be a more efficient way to run the docload functions on ajax loaded documents

Comment: @Andrew: I don't think the OP is using `load`, judging by the demos for jQuery Tools. You can specify a target html page and the jQuery Tools will use AJAX behind the scenes to retrieve the content.

Comment: @zobgib How is this redundant at all?

Comment: @Andrew W.: Ah I see. That's unfortunate given the utter lack of good API docs on that site.

Comment: @Andrew M. Agreed. My team dropped jQueryTools because simple problems like the one the OP is having don't have simple solutions.

Comment: Yes - I don't use the load method, jquery tools hides that from me...but after more reading it really looks like the init code should go AFTER the < /html> tag...strange.

Comment: @Michelle Nothing can be after the `</html>` tag and be valid HTML. Further, it will have no effect if the AJAX load is after that code is called.

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of a long shot, but I'm pretty sure you could tap into the `onClick` event. I *believe* this is fired after the tab content is loaded, even via AJAX. You would write something like this:

```
$("ul.tabs").tabs("div.panes > div", {
    effect: 'ajax',
    onClick: function(event, index) {
        $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane({showArrows: true});
    }
});
```

I hope this works for you. If it does, it's severely undocumented.

Comment: Of course if the `onclick` event callback is run _before_ the AJAX call… (but there isn't any way to do that from what I can see)

Comment: @Andrew M. You can define an event handler for `onBeforeClick`. That and glancing at the source makes me think this might work.

Comment: What does `onBeforeClick` even mean? Is the browser sensing an imminent click before it happens? Haha

Comment: @Andrew M: It's a custom jQuery Tools event. Here's where it's raised: https://github.com/jquerytools/jquerytools/blob/master/src/tabs/tabs.js#L148

Comment: Oh I see. It's after the real click, but before the `onclick` event that it runs. Weird.

Comment: If that's a tab based method, tha would mean running the initialization code each time the tab is entered...not ideal...just my 2c

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your issue properly , there will be two ways to fix this issue .

a ) load the script prior to tab load , so you should not wait for the script to load

b ) load the scripts dynamically to main page and invoke a call back

in case b you will should do sht like this:

```
 function loadScript(sScriptSrc, oCallback) {
    var oHead = document.getElementById('head')[0];
    var oScript = document.createElement('script');
    oScript.type = 'text/javascript';
    oScript.src = sScriptSrc;
    // most browsers
    oScript.onload = oCallback;
    // IE 6 & 7
    oScript.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 'complete') {
            oCallback();
        }
    }
    oHead.appendChild(oScript);
}
```

To me its structural issue , not script issue . It means , WHEN/HOW/WHERE tab data and script is loaded on ajax call. A better way will be if you share demo link where this is happening . I ll be glad help .

Let me know if I am understanding your issue